# Save/Load functions not reloading textfield values properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I'm relatively new to developing iOS apps.

I'm developing a "note-app" where users can type in info in a text field, hit Save and then have the opportunity to completely exit the app, re-open, and the info gets loaded with a button.

I'm currently using Xcode 4.5.

I've coded all of it and something weird happens. I type in something in every textfield (I have twelve), hit Save, and exit the app. When I reopen the app and hit Load, the text from textfield 12 loads in textfield 1. And all the other text are gone. Why is that happening?

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> 
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField3;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField4;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField5;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField6;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField7;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField8;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField9;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField10;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField11;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField12;

    IBOutlet UILabel *loaded; 
}

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)load:(id)sender;
```

SecondViewController.m

```
@implementation SecondViewController

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{    
    //First Save String
    NSString *savestring =myTextField.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"saveString"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    //Second Save String
    NSString *savestring2 =myTextField2.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults2 setObject:savestring2 forKey:@"saveString2"];
    [defaults2 synchronize];

    //Third Save String
    NSString *savestring3 =myTextField3.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults3 setObject:savestring3 forKey:@"saveString3"];
    [defaults3 synchronize];

    //Fourth Save String
    NSString *savestring4 =myTextField4.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults4 setObject:savestring4 forKey:@"saveString4"];
    [defaults4 synchronize];

    //Fifth Save String
    NSString *savestring5 =myTextField5.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults5 setObject:savestring5 forKey:@"saveString5"];
    [defaults5 synchronize];

    //Sixth Save String
    NSString *savestring6 =myTextField6.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults6 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults6 setObject:savestring6 forKey:@"saveString6"];
    [defaults6 synchronize];

    //Seventh Save String
    NSString *savestring7 =myTextField7.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults7 setObject:savestring7 forKey:@"saveString7"];
    [defaults7 synchronize];

    //Eight Save String
    NSString *savestring8 =myTextField8.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults8 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults8 setObject:savestring8 forKey:@"saveString8"];
    [defaults8 synchronize];

    //Ninth Save String
    NSString *savestring9 =myTextField9.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults9 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults9 setObject:savestring9 forKey:@"saveString9"];
    [defaults9 synchronize];

    //Tenth Save String
    NSString *savestring10 =myTextField10.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults10 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults10 setObject:savestring10 forKey:@"saveString10"];
    [defaults10 synchronize];

    //Eleventh Save String
    NSString *savestring11 =myTextField11.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults11 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults11 setObject:savestring11 forKey:@"saveString11"];
    [defaults11 synchronize];

    //Twelvth Save String
    NSString *savestring12 =myTextField12.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults12 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults12 setObject:savestring12 forKey:@"saveString12"];
    [defaults12 synchronize];

    loaded.text = @"Dine notater ble lagret!"; 
}

-(IBAction)load:(id)sender;
{    
    //First Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"saveString"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Second Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring2 = [defaults2 objectForKey:@"saveString2"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring2];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Third Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring3 = [defaults3 objectForKey:@"saveString3"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring3];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Forth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring4 = [defaults4 objectForKey:@"saveString4"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring4];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Fifth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring5 = [defaults5 objectForKey:@"saveString5"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring5];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Sixth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults6 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring6 = [defaults6 objectForKey:@"saveString6"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring6];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Seventh Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring7 = [defaults7 objectForKey:@"saveString7"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring7];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Eight Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults8 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring8 = [defaults8 objectForKey:@"saveString8"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring8];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Ninth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults9 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring9 = [defaults9 objectForKey:@"saveString9"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring9];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Tenth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults10 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring10 = [defaults10 objectForKey:@"saveString10"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring10];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Eleventh Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults11 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring11 = [defaults11 objectForKey:@"saveString11"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring11];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

    //Twelvth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults12 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring12 = [defaults12 objectForKey:@"saveString12"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring12];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
}
```

For those who are *not* Norwegian, "Dine notater ble lastet inn!" and "Dine notater ble lagret!" mean saved and loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every where you have setting the data on myTextField `[myTextField setText:loadstring];`
it should be **myTextfield1,2,3....** and so on .
           Also you don't have to initialize NSUserDefaults every time .`NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];` just define it at the top of the function.

Comment: Oh my god, it was that easy!! I guess my eyes stood in the way! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As you load each string, you are setting 'myTextField' over and over again. That is the first field.

BTW, it is not necessary to get a pointer to the standard user defaults for each field you want to read/write.

Comment: I noticed that, eventually. I just followed a tutorial saying I should do it like that. I'll look into it next time. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Glad that worked out. I think @V-Xtreme answered your question first, and his/her answer is more complete than mine. I would suggest you accept his/her answer instead. Good luck with your project!